# Is 内向きの really the best word to describe "introvert?"

Tags: word-requests

**Hello,**

Ever since I came across this word **内向きの for "Introvert"** online, I have been questioning whether its the proper japanese for it? I'm planning to use the word for a profile, and wanted to make sure i was using the correct word.

I have noticed several variations of this word.

**Thanks a bunch!
DCardinal**

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. 内向的(な性格)、内気(な性格)、内省的(な性格) would be more common.